# Can't get some Memcached values by key

Tags: php, zend-framework2, memcached, memcachedb

We have two servers with Memcached on both of them.

First one is so called `memcachedSetter` and second is `memcachedGetter`.

Server `memcachedSetter` create `uniq keys` via php `createUID` function and extended searching parameters as value (we get searching flights parameters and bypass is on provider`s SOAP Server)

```
public function createUID() {
    return md5(uniqid(rand(),1));
}
```

The second way point is appear when user selecting one of returned flight variant to book it.

`memcachedGetter` want to join selected flight variant with request requisites. That is example of Set and Get value **memcachedGetterServer** code example.

memcachedSetter**Set**Action:

```
public function memcachedSetterSetAction() {

    $cacheConfig = new \Zend\Config\Config...;

    $content = new \stdClass();
    $content->content = 'Some search criteria';

    $cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(...);

    $cache->setItem('taskA9E3..89', $content);
    $cache->setItem('requestFC20..60', $content);

    $cache->setItem('taskD987..76', $content);
    $cache->setItem('request72D4..4A', $content);

    die;
}
```

memcachedSetter**Get**Action:

```
public function memcachedSetterGetAction() {
    echo "<br> 1. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskA9E3..89');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 2. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('requestFC20..60');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 3. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskD987..76');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 4. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('request72D4..4A');
    var_dump($requestData );
}
```

This way we setting and getting both each of key/values. And then magic appears when we try to get value by key on th e second server:

memcachedGetter**Get**Action:

```
public function memcachedSetterGetAction() {
    echo "<br> 1. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskA9E3..89');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 2. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('requestFC20..60');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 3. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskD987..76');
    var_dump($requestData );

    echo "<br> 4. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('request72D4..4A');
    var_dump($requestData );
}
```

The same code on the memcached**Getter** will return just a part of values instant full set as memcached**Setter** did:

```
1. object(stdClass)#331 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." } 
2. object(stdClass)#332 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." } 
3. object(stdClass)#336 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." } 
4. object(stdClass)#339 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." }
```

vs

```
1. object(stdClass)#335 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." } 
2. object(stdClass)#331 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Some sea..." } 
3. NULL 
4. NULL
```